# full screen slider in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I installed the easy full screen slide plugin(https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-fullscreen-slider/ ) but unfortunately I can't find the shortcode that I have to use to show the plugin. Could any one help me and tell me what is the short code I have to use to show the plugin?

Comment: Have you followed [these](https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-fullscreen-slider/installation/) steps? We need more information to be able to help. What steps did you take and where did it go wrong?

Comment: yes, I followed them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This plugin has no shortcodes at all.

You basically have to go to your preferred page/post and edit the plugin settings there in the "Easy Fullscreen Slider - Settings" meta box, somewhere below the WYSIWYG editor. This controls the slideshow settings on a per page/post basis.

Also, you have a global settings page, called "Easy Fullscreen Slider". This way you can control the global settings that apply to all sliders (they can be overwritten on a per page/post basis as described above).